# Polyfilla for Object.defineProperty Getter/Setter

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I was wondering if there's a backwards-compat fix for the newish Object.defineProperty API in ECMAScript 5(?) that allows you to have getter and setter functions?

My initial thought is this is not possible to polyfill, given it happens at a lower level in the runtime than is possible to hook in to.. But I would love to be proved wrong in this case!

So to summarise, how can I simulate the implicit getter and setter mechanism for older browsers?

Many thanks

Comment: Not all browser do support this, indeed. You simply can't use them there and have to resort to explicit setter/getter methods.

Comment: Thought as much, shame as its such a great addition to the language